# Outlook 2016 unable to connect to Exchange 2007

Tags: mac, ms-office, exchange

I have just been hired at a new company that does not seem to have much of a Mac presence... yet.  They aren't blocking Mac's specifically(as far as I can tell and others have told me).

On my company supplied PC I can get Outlook 2010 to work inside and outside the network(without VPN), so Outlook anywhere must be running.

If my PC can run Outlook on the outside via Outlook anywhere.  I need some help understanding my my Mac cannot.  Any thoughts on what may be blocked or preventing me from connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://products.office.com/en-us/office-system-requirements?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Office 2016 requires Exchange 2010, at a minimum, for "certain advanced functionality".

"Outlook 2016 does not support connections to Exchange Server 2007."

Comment: Thanks for the link willWorkForCookies.  I had a fear that might be the case.  However, has anyone connected from Outlook 2016 to Exch07?

Comment: I just switch employers.  At my last employer one of my clients was going through an 2007->2013 migration right around the time Office 2016 released and I updated.  I want to say there was a brief period where I was connecting to Exch07 via Outlook 2016, but I couldn't swear to it.  This new employer is much larger and has much stricter security settings.  They also don't seem to have any Macs in the organization.  I suspect they are port blocking in some way.  I am not looking for advanced functionality, just the basics.  Any different ports used on Outlook for mac 2016 vs. Windows version?

Comment: Not to my knowledge - I doubt it was working at all.  If it was I would give credit to something being cached.  I'm pretty sure most of the configuration around Exchange & ActiveSync is DNS related, when it comes to Outlook being able to connector not.  Beyond protocol versions of course.

Comment: willWorkForCoockies, thank you for your help.  I reinstalled Outlook 2011 and it was able to connect to the Exchange2007 server.  So you are correct, the issue is Outlook 2016 is not yet compatible.  This new organization is in the midst of an upgrade to Exchange 2013.  I wonder if it is the CAS or Mailbox roles that need to be upgraded to 2013 for Outlook 2016 to connect.  Either way this is just a temporary inconvenience and I can use Outlook 2011 in the meantime.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool. Glad you were able to confirm.